# Variables are not defined in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a google script for a guessing game, while variables A2 and B2 are not defined. How can I solve this problem?

The code I had would be:

```
function function1() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var A1 = activeSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  var B1 = activeSheet.getRange(1,3).getValue();
  var A2 = activeSheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var B2 = activeSheet.getRange(2,3).getValue();

  if(A1 === "apple"){
    activeSheet.getRange(1,3).setValue("correct");
    } else {
      activeSheet.getRange(1,3).setValue("Wrong");
  }
  if(B1 === "correct"){
    activeSheet.getRange(2,1).setValue("what is the colour of an orange?");
    } 
  }
  if(A2 === "orange"){
    activeSheet.getRange(2,3).setValue("Correct");
    } else {
      activeSheet.getRance(2,3).setValue("Wrong");
  }
  if(B2 === "Correct"){
    activeSheet.getRange(2,1).setValue("(Another question");
    }
```

Comment: are there values in those ranges?

Comment: Cell A1 is `getRange(1, 1)`.... (1, 2) is cell B1.

Answer (score 1):

### Use an `onEdit` trigger

for a [simple onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) you just need to change the name of your function to `onEdit()`. The function will run automatically when an edit is made to the sheet.

Furthermore, your code contains some other issues:

- `if(A2 === "orange"){...` is not inside the function
- Case sensitivity is not respected ("correct" is not the same like "Correct")
- The [range notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column]) is conflicting (e.g. `getRange(1,3).setValue("correct");` and then `if(B1 === "correct")` - the range notation for `B1` would be `(1,2)`

Have a look at the sample below, I hope it solves your issue:

```
function onEdit() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var A1 = activeSheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var B1 = activeSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  var A2 = activeSheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var B2 = activeSheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();

  if(A1 == "apple"){
    activeSheet.getRange(1,2).setValue("Correct");
    activeSheet.getRange(1,3).setValue("what is the colour of an orange?");
  } else {
    activeSheet.getRange(1,2).setValue("Wrong");
    activeSheet.getRange(1,3).setValue("");
  }
  if(A2 == "orange"){
    activeSheet.getRange(2,2).setValue("Correct");
    activeSheet.getRange(2,3).setValue("Another question");
  } else {
    activeSheet.getRange(2,2).setValue("Wrong");
    activeSheet.getRange(2,3).setValue("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

I would also like to know if I allow multiple answers, how should I write the code? For example, "apple" and "Apple" are correct answers.